# Getting Vim FuzzyFinder to stop blinking when searching?

Tags: vim, fuzzyfinder

I got FuzzyFinder set up, and it works pretty well, but when I'm doing ":FufCoverageFile", the file matching dropdown blinks every time I add or remove a character. When I'm typing to get search for a file, this turns out to be very, very distracting. Is there something I can do to stop the file finder from blinking distractingly?

https://github.com/vim-scripts/FuzzyFinder

vim --version:

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Jul 31 2011 19:27:29)

Running OS X Lion.

Comment: Have you tried CommandT?, I never used fuzzyfinder because people were review commandt better than it. I use it on OS X with MacVim without problems and it's really fast https://wincent.com/products/command-t. Docs: http://git.wincent.com/command-t.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/doc/command-t.txt

Answer (score 0):

This does not have to do with FuzzyFinder but instead has to do with your terminal not supporting whatever colors your menu is trying to be displayed in. These are set by `Pmenu` and `PmenuSel`.

Check `:hi Pmenu` and `:hi PmenuSel` to see what colors they are set to. Try `:hi clear Pmenu` and `:hi clear PmenuSel` to see if that stops it. If it does then it confirms my diagnosis. If your terminal supports 256 colors you may need to enable it. You can check your current $TERM with `:echo $TERM`.